# How to execute a script when chromecast turns on

Tags: google-apps, chromecast

Can anyone know Is there a way to execute a script when chromecast is turned on?

Any startup Url can be configured anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a thing for chromecast

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this it's not possible, it just won't be easy or robust. For instance, you could create a DHCP reservation for your Chromecast on your DHCP server (likely a home router). Then you could write a script that would ping that IP continuously, then when it get's a response a script would be ran.